# Making a dynamic array of objects and Initializing it

Tags: c++, arrays

i have two classes that are Student and StudentArray.

In class Student, i have declared some student's attributes like name, ID, age etc.

In StudentArray class, i want to create an array of Student type. StudentArray class also contains some functions like Insert that will insert data in the Student type array. I want to add complete student's data like name,age,id etc of one student at the same index of the Array but i can't understand how to do that.

I also can't understand how to initialize the array in the constructor of StudentArray class. This is what i have done so far.

Student Class

```
class student
{
    public:
    string name;
    int id;
    int age;
    string semester;
    string degreeprogram;
};
```

StudentArray Class

```
class StudentArray
{
public:
    student *s;
    int used;

    StudentArray();
    ~StudentArray();
    void input();
    void Insert(string n,int i,int a, string s, string dp);
    int Search(string n, int i);
    void DeleteAnyStudent(string n, int i);
    void DeleteAll();
    void Edit(string n, int i);
    void show();
};
```

Constructor of StudentArray class

```
StudentArray::StudentArray()
{
    s = new student[100];
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        s[i] = new student(); //ERROR HERE
    }
    used = 0;
}
```

Insert Function in StudentArray class

```
void StudentArray::Insert(string n,int i,int a, string s, string dp)
{
    s[used].name = n;  //ERROR HERE
    s[used].id = i;    //ERROR HERE
    s[used].age = a;   //ERROR HERE
    s[used].semester = s;  //ERROR HERE
    s[used].degreeprogram = dp;  //ERROR HERE
    used++;
}
```

i am using code blocks.

In the constructor of StudentArray, error message is `"no match for operator 'operator=' (operand types are ;student' and 'student*' )". In the insert function, the error message is "error: request for member 'id' in 's.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator[]<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(((std::basic_string<char>::size_type)((StudentArray*)this)‌​->StudentArray::used‌​))', which is of non-class type 'char'|"`

In the insert function, same error is thrown at every line after which i have written "ERROR HERE", only the name of the variable like name, id or age etc changes

Comment: "ERROR HERE". Is it compile-time error or run-time error? Any error message?

Comment: Besides, why not `std::vector`?

Comment: i am using code blocks, so it only throws error when i build and run the program. In the constructor of StudentArray, error message is "no match for operator 'operator=' (operand types are ;student' and 'student*' )". In the insert function, the error message is "error: request for member 'id' in 's.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator[]<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(((std::basic_string<char>::size_type)((StudentArray*)this)->StudentArray::used))', which is of non-class type 'char'|"

Comment: in the insert function, same error is thrown at every line after which i have written "ERROR HERE". only the name of the variable like name, id or age etc changes

Comment: Firstly, the error message is literal and obvious. Secondly, the verb "throw" does not mean that. Thirdly, edit the post to paste the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `s = new Student[100];` you have an array of 100 default initialised `Student` objects, which I think is exactly what you want.

But you then try to assign to each one a pointer to another, newly allocated object. That can't work - you're trying to assign a pointer to an object - and isn't needed anyway. If you just delete that loop entirely you'll be better off.

EDIT: Your second problem is because you have a parameter named `s` which is a string. That hides your member variable called `s`. You need to rename one of them. (It shouldn't be hard to find a better name!)

Comment: I can post the error message at "s[used].name = n" which might help you understand the problem. The error message is "error: request for member 'name' in 's.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator[]<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(((std::basic_string<char>::size_type)((StudentArray*)this)->StudentArray::used))', which is of non-class type 'char'|"

Comment: You need to post a minimal example of code that shows the problem. And please edit your question if you want to add information, rather than putting it in comments.

Answer (score -1):

Simply member `s` is `student*` therefore `s[i]` is of type `student`.

I think you wanted to have `pointer to pointer`, declare `s` as `student**`

Comment: What's bad about this answer?